# Display a custom help message in TCLAP

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm using the [TCLAP](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/) library to do some command line argument parsing. It's pretty great: except for the help messages it prints. Those are kind of ugly.

For instance, this is the output:

```
USAGE: 

   ./a.out  [-r] -n <string> [--] [--version] [-h]


Where: 

   -r,  --reverse
     Print name backwards

   -n <string>,  --name <string>
     (required)  Name to print

   --,  --ignore_rest
     Ignores the rest of the labeled arguments following this flag.

   --version
     Displays version information and exits.

   -h,  --help
     Displays usage information and exits.


   Command description message
```

of this program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tclap/CmdLine.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  try {  
    TCLAP::CmdLine cmd("Command description message", ' ', "0.9");
    TCLAP::ValueArg<std::string> nameArg("n","name","Name to print",true,"homer","string");

    cmd.add( nameArg );
    TCLAP::SwitchArg reverseSwitch("r","reverse","Print name backwards", cmd, false);
    cmd.parse( argc, argv );

    std::string name = nameArg.getValue();
    bool reverseName = reverseSwitch.getValue();

    if ( reverseName ){
      std::reverse(name.begin(),name.end());
      std::cout << "My name (spelled backwards) is: " << name << std::endl;
    } else{
      std::cout << "My name is: " << name << std::endl;
    }
  } catch (TCLAP::ArgException &e) {
    std::cerr << "error: " << e.error() << " for arg " << e.argId() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

when run with `./a.out -h`.

I want more creative control: I want to make my very own help message!

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is it that you want?  I always thought that the _automagic_ help creations was a core strength -- but I sometimes subclassed the output to make it more compact, ie fever empty lines.

Comment: I want to print a big block of text that I have written and formatted myself.

Comment: Entirely doable.  Subclass TCLAP to myTCLAP, replace the default help method with a custom one that takes your formatted text as an additional ctor argument.

Answer (score 3):

The `TCLAP::CmdLineOutput` class is the one responsible for printing help (or usage) messages.

If you want TCLAP to print a custom message, you must first derive from the class mentioned above and add its instance to your `TCLAP::CmdLine` object like:

```
cmd.setOutput(new CustomHelpOutput());
```

Here is an example of a custom `TCLAP::CmdLineOutput`:

```
class CustomHelpOutput : public TCLAP::StdOutput {
public:
    virtual void usage(TCLAP::CmdLineInterface& _cmd) override {
        std::cout << "My program is called " << _cmd.getProgramName() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Note that you are the one responsible for cleaning up after your custom object, because TCLAP has a flag that disables its deletion [in the setter](https://github.com/eile/tclap/blob/f41dcb5ce3d063c9fe95623193bba693338f3edb/include/tclap/CmdLine.h#L578).

```
inline void CmdLine::setOutput(CmdLineOutput* co)
{
    if ( !_userSetOutput )
        delete _output;
    _userSetOutput = true;
    _output = co;
}
```